# How to use bitcoin -rpcwallet flag in deno RPC

Tags: javascript, typescript, rpc, deno, bitcoind

I want to create an address in a wallet with bitcoin-cli, the command for this will look like this for the loaded wallet `bitcoin-cli getnewaddress some_users` and with Deno I can just do

```
import { createRemote } from "https://deno.land/x/gentleRpc/rpcClient.ts";

let Node = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:8332");
Node.port = "8332";
Node.username = "some_user";
Node.password = "some_password";

const remote = createRemote(Node);

const address = remote.getnewaddress(addressLabel);
```

I would love to know how to use deno rpc for cases where I need to specify the `-rpcwallet` flag, like this `bitcoin-cli -rpcwallet=some_unique_wallet getnewaddress some_users`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after reading the doc further, I realised I can do this by passing the wallet name to the url like this `http://127.0.0.1:8332/wallet/${walletName}` or just this `http://127.0.0.1:8332/wallet/` for the default wallet.

So the code will look like this,

```js
    createConnection(walletName?: string) {
        const uri = !!walletName ? 
            'http://127.0.0.1:8332/wallet/${walletName}' : 
            'http://127.0.0.1:8332/wallet/';

        let Node = new URL(uri);
        Node.port = "8332";
        Node.username = "some_user";
        Node.password = "some_password";
        return createRemote(Node);
    }
```